# WebStorm does not recognized some Sass partial files with underscore

Tags: sass, webstorm

I don't know why but last Friday, my WebStorm project has stopped recognizing some Sass files and displayed them as text file:

[image]

Comment: Usually indicates user mistake -- you most likely have created that file in a "wrong way" (I mean -- without looking at a screen or paying attention to what's happening there). Quite likely that you have created that file as `_theme` first, IDE asked you what you wish to do with the file of unknown type (file has no extension) ... and you selected default "Text" file type .. and only then (at some point later) renamed it to `_theme.scss` .. which is a bit too late. Now you need to remove that wrong entry from the settings.

Comment: I always create my files with an extension. I've made a test this morning creating a _themes.scss who was recognize as Sass file. I rename it, removing the «s» and again. it is recognize again as a text file. Is there any cache file or something in Webstorm I can delete? I've delete the .idea folder but it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | File Types`
3. Find `Text` entry in top list
4. Find and remove offending entry in bottom list (will be `_theme.scss` or similar)

Comment: Wow!! I don't know why this file type _theme.scss was added as Text file type, but thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, I think I undertand why. There's a menu option «Mark has Plain Text» right under «Delete». Maybe I click that accidentaly.

Comment: @JonathanAnctil Extremely unlikely for 2 simple (for me) reasons: **1)** such file will have slightly different icon (try it -- you can reverse the action by "unmarking" that file in a same way as you mark it -- via right click); **2)** Such file is not stored at that settings path -- it's stored in separate config file where all entries have absolute file path (so marked file in one project/folder will not affect similarly named files in other project/folder) and no dedicated GUI to edit them (unmakring is done by issuing opposite command in a same way -- e.g. context menu in Project View).